# Is there a shortcut to open the Node Command Prompt in Any Folder?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, node.js

For example, you can open a Windows Command Prompt in any folder with the shortcut:

- Shift key + right-click

Is there any similar shortcut available to open the Node command prompt in any folder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this. But you can create one for the right-click of a folder (just like the "Open command prompt here" examples on the internet).

Create a file named `Open Node-prompt here.reg` and double click it (and click Yes and OK):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\Node]
@="Open Node here"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\Node\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k \"pushd \"%V\" & \"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\nodevars.bat\"\""
```

This will start the normal (`cmd.exe`) prompt in the **correct chosen directory** with first setting all the necessary variables for `node.exe`. After doing the `dir`s and `cd`s you can call your `node program.js` just like normal.

Comment: I followed your steps, and am able to successfully test the console.log as you did. But, commands like dir and cd do not work. I think that the repl may be opening instead of the command prompt.

Comment: Then you need to explain "the Node command prompt". If you want commands like `dir` and `cd` why is the normal command prompt not sufficient? How do you normally start this "Node command prompt"?

Comment: The node command prompt is similar to the normal command prompt, but gives you the added capability of running node apps with the command "node [path/to/app].js". The node command prompt is installed by default when you install node on Windows. Here is a somewhat related SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654610/run-hello-world-from-node-js-command-prompt-in-windows-7

Comment: I think you misunderstood that post. There is **nothing** named "Node command prompt". You can start `node.exe` with a parameter of a `.js` program. You can do this from the normal command prompt (You see the `cmd.exe` in the title bar in that post). If you want `dir` and `cd` commands you just drop in the `Command prompt` (with the Shift+Right-click) and run `node program.js`. The problem is probably that in the Shift+Right-click cmd.exe the path to `node.exe` is not set (you'll get a `'node' is not recognized as an internal ...etc`). If that's the case let me know. We can fix that.

Comment: Yes, I do get a "'node' is not a recognized..." message when I try to run a program from the normal command prompt. Just so I understand about the Node Command Prompt, do you mean that when I choose Start -> Programs -> Node.js -> Node Command Prompt, that I am actually opening the normal command prompt in disguise?

Comment: Yes, the "Node Command Prompt" is just a call to the normal `cmd.exe` (you can check this in the properties of the shortcut). But now i understand what you want. The "Node Command Prompt" calls the `nodevars.bat` where the correct path to `node.exe` is set. I adjusted my answer and it should be what you want.

Comment: After doing this, CMD doesn't allow me to do cd without adding /d to it.. how can I reverse this?

Comment: @KenVernaillen You mean `cd ..` doesn't even work? `cd /d drive:\path` is for changing driveletter and path but `cd path` should still work for the same drive as that you're on.

Comment: it works again. nvm

Answer (score 8):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> then type `cmd` and hit enter

This will open cmd in your current folder, in case anybody is looking for an alternate method.

The `cmd` for windows is same as the one node uses. I have tested with node commands. Thanks Rik (in comments) for the info.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Instead of hacking around, this solution simply opens the cmd in current folder. Nice!

Comment: This works for me :)